# <lightning-combobox> vertical list box height

Tags: lightning-web-components

In LWC, can't able to set height of the list. Attached screenshot for reference.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your combo box under div and assign custom css like below

Html Code:

```
<template>
    <div class="table">
        <lightning-combobox
                name="progress"
                label="Status"
                value={value}
                placeholder="Select Progress"
                options={options}
                onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>
</div>
</template>
```

CSS Code:

```
.table{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```